# Table Profile "no such table"

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a problem, the debug always says no such table Profile but I did syncdb and checked all the connections what could be the problem other then that?

Comment: Can you please provide some more information? your model and the traceback..

Comment: Did you add your app containing Profile model to INSTALLED_APPS before running syncdb?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem is that you edited your model and syncdb didn't actually modify the table.

Open your DB client and make sure they match up. Otherwise, drop the table and resync and you should be good

Your models need to match the DB set up or confusion is imminent.

Make sure python `manage.py sql myapp` looks the same as `sql: show schema (myapp)`

Source: Hours of frustration :)